# using SOAPHeader class to update SOAPMessage Header java

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

Scenario: I have to call a WSDL based webService and parse its response. 
Problem: I am having problem to update the SOAPMessage SOAP Header & SOAP Body OR SOAP Enevelope,  which I can create using the classes generated from the WSimport tool.

I have generated java classes for the provided wsdl using WSimport tool. There were many classess generated and among them I found one class which has objects to create SOAP Header, Body and other details as [shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eqte.jpg). My problem is that when I generate my soapbody and header from the provided class, I am not able to add it to the SOAP Message which i want to post to the webservice in order to get the response. Is there any method that i need to create to generate SOAP message ?

```
{

    Body mySoapBody = new Body();
    Header mySoapHeader = new Header();

    Envelope mySoapEnevelope = new Envelope();

    //Generate SOAP Body
    mySoapBody.getAny().add(objofIdentifyCustomerClass);
    //Generate SOAP Header
    mySoapHeader.getAny().add(emfHeader);
    //Generate SOAP Enevelope
    mySoapEnevelope.setBody(mySoapBody);
    mySoapEnevelope.setHeader(mySoapHeader);

    //This is an Issue, Cant add generated Header to the SOAP Message
    SOAPMessage soapMsg= MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage( );

    //MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    //SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();

    soapMsg.getSOAPBody().addDocument(getRE02XMLBodyMsg(ciscoRE02Request));

    // How to add/update SOAP Header in the SOAPMessage ???? 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was not understanding the process correctly. I read blogs of this location which helped me resolve the problem and made the code efficient:

http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/

If you have problem writing to a WebService I highly encourage you to read this article.

Regards,
Nevin